# Error scanning barcode with Ionic/cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I have an Ionic project and I installed this plugin to scan qrcodes:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git
```

But when I run the app on a samsung s5 device with Android 6.0 I get a camera error:
"**Sorry, the Android camera encountered a problem. You may need to restart the device**"
[image]

Any ideas of what causes this issue?

I have tested with:

```
ionic run android -l -c
ionic run android
```

This is my code executed when I press a button:

```
$scope.scanBarcode = function() {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(imageData) {
      console.log("Barcode text -> " + imageData.text);
      console.log("Barcode Format -> " + imageData.format);
      console.log("Cancelled -> " + imageData.cancelled); // prints: cancelled
    }, function(error) {
      console.log("An error happened -> " + error);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Hi .. I have the same problem with Experia Z5 ... on other device it works... my suggestion is to try to set the minimum sdk version for andoird .. than try to add in config.xml this:   <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" version="5.0.1" src="https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git"/>

Comment: Did that solve your problem? Yet, I am using another plugin "https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git"

Answer (score 2):

For this issue you can try either of below solutions:
1)  It is permission issue with android 6. So to fix the issue configure platform to android 5.0.

OR if you are using MI note 4 you can try below additional steps:

There is another permission required in MIUI secruity system and after enabling it, camera started working.
Following are the steps you can follow to update the setting:
1) Go to Security.
2) Click on “Permissions” and again select “Permissions”
3) Now from the list, click on “Camera”.
4) It will list all the apps installed. Look for your app and enable the permission.

Reff: http://sforsuresh.in/cordova-sorry-android-camera-encountered-problem/

Answer (score 1):

This is what solved my problema, in the config.xml file in the "android" platform section I put:

```
<platform name="android">
     <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22"/>
</platform>
```